# How to wait more after explicit wait's until condition is done?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with the test method's code below. The test bot first clicks on the generate button and then waits explicitly till the element (`p-datatable-tbody`) which is a container for the results is populated.

Everything works fine actually but, I can't wait more after Explicit Wait's Until method's condition is done. I want to do it to see if my table is really populated. Because currently, I see the log but once the table is populated, the test gets closed instantly.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("GenerateButton")).Click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(150));
IWebElement customersTable = driver.FindElement(By.Id("CustomersTable"));
IWebElement rowsContainer = customersTable.FindElement(By.ClassName("p-datatable-tbody"));
wait.Until(condition => rowsContainer.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*")).Count > 1);
Console.WriteLine("Generated Customers Count: " + rowsContainer.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*")).Count);
//Thread.Sleep(30000); -> this doesn't work
bool dataExist = rowsContainer.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*")).Count > 1;
Assert.IsTrue(dataExist);
```

I tried to wait with `Thread.Sleep`, but it didn't work out. It waits while the explicit wait is also waiting.

Comment: Take screenshot of the page after writing to the log. The screenshot can be used as a test evidence.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
await wait.Until(async condition =>
{
    var notEmpty = rowsContainer.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*")).Count > 1;
    await Task.Delay(30_000);
    bool dataExist = rowsContainer.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*")).Count > 1;
    await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Data exists: {dataExist}");    
    return notEmpty;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Shawn said you have to create screenshot inside [TearDown] for handle your problem better.

I suppose your table element is reloading in DOM during adding table data and you got exception for old element rowsContainer. After this method call

```
wait.Until(condition => rowsContainer.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*")).Count > 1)
```

you should filtering table element once again, because your table element probably was refreshed.

```
IWebElement customersTable = driver.FindElement(By.Id("CustomersTable"))
```